# How to add session in android application?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm making an android application in which there are different activities connected to Home (MainActivty) activity and vice-verse. I want to close my application whenever i press back key from home activity. But it takes me to previous activity where it is came from. how can i do this. Please someone help me in this, i'm new to android. Thanks.............

Here is my code:

```
  btn_daily.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_health.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_diet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_exercise.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_yoga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityE.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityF.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        dialogOnBackPress();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

protected void dialogOnBackPress() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Exit Alert !!")
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that activities other then `MainActivity`, has also some mechanism to navigate to other activities. So while navigating to other activity, don't forget to use `finish()` to destroy that current activity.

And if your application has other mechanism like there is some home button which takes you to home screen from any navigation activity, then at that time open `MainActivity` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

Hence by doing so, you will not have back stack of extra activity and back button from `MainActivity` will close the app.

**EDIT :**  For scenario you have mentioned in the comment, you have to use following code on Home button click.

```
 btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes..you are right there is a home button which takes you to home screen from any navigation activity, then what i have to do for that?

Comment: Thanks for the help.... Now i understand the concept of FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This is the thing what i want... :)

Comment: @Zohaib thats great. One thing to note that you MUST not finish the MainActivity or HomeActivity while navigating to other activity, when you are using this kind of mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in `onBackPressed` method..

```
startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this,HomeActivity.class"));
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have not added `intent flags`
try this

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Exit Alert !!")
       .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 finish();
        } 
     })
```

Comment: it's working.... but start's giving an error message "unfortunately application has stopped" when i start the application again for the first time and launch successfully on second attempt. how to remove this error.

Comment: If it is working then please up-vote the answer :D 
Can you post log cat error?

Comment: Thanks for the help....half of your answer is right and remaining part, i figured out.